# Using Hibernate and JDBC together from different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I want to use Spring-Hibernate and JDBC together in my application.

Hibernate should do all the updating and writing from one thread and other threads should just be able to read from the database without too much synchronization effort.

Will those JDBC-using threads deliver correct results (if they read from the database a short time after calling `persist()` or `merge()`) or could it happen, that Hibernate
has not flushed any updates and therefore other threads return wrong database entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Wrong" depends on the isolation level you set for your connection pool.

I think it can work if Hibernate and Spring share the same connection pool and you set the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE for all connections.

Long-running transactions will be the problem.  If all your write operations are fast you won't block.  If you don't commit and flush updates quickly the read operations will either have to block and wait OR allow "dirty reads".

Comment: I would like to avoid the SERIALIZABLE isolation level for perfomance...But if I allow dirty reads for the JDBC threads and don't set the isolation level to SERIALIZEABLE I should get the proper values in most cases, am I right? EDIT: the reads are just to give to user information, they are not critical.

Answer (score 0):

That depends. You're basically describing a race condition - if you want to make sure that your read-thread only reads after the write-thread has persisted, you will have to look into thread synchronization methodology.

Cheers,

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of that. I know that this is not perfectly clear from my question, but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Fair enough. Still, the answer remains the same - there can be no guarantees bar additional assumptions... What is the use case (I'm curious)?

Comment: I have an application with a lot existing queries which use plain MYSQL over JDBC. I have to perform updates and the transactions, might take quite some time and I would like to use Hibernate as using just JDBC is a pain in the a**. Those queries are not really critical, nothing but user information depends on them so the race condition depends on user reaction when he is provided with incomplete data.